# peewee db.close() not working as expected

Tags: python, peewee

I tried implementing a simple model using peewee. Since I wanted to reuse functions that do queries often inside different contexts, I wanted to ensure that the connection to my db is opened and closed only 1 time for any call using a stack like this:

```
connected = 0

def connect():
    global connected
    if connected == 0:
        db.connect()
    connected +=1

def disconnect():
    global connected
    if connected == 0:
        raise ... # should not happen
    if connected == 1:
        db.close()
    connected -= 1
```

My functions then look like this:

```
def get_something():
    try:
        connect()
        # execute query
    finally:
        disconnect()
```

However, the second time the function is called, peewee complains that the connection is already open. I'm completely sure that db.close() is correctly called. The fun thing is, if I manually add

```
connected += 1
disconnect()
```

between the two calls, it works fine.

In my opinion, this should make absolutely no difference. Already checked if it's a timing issue by adding sleep to the finally's disconnect(); same behavior. Does anybody have an idea if this is indeed a peewee issue or there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you implicitly execute a query before the connect() step, then peewee will have already opened a connection.

I'd check to see where you might be executing a query outside the scope of the connect/close wrappers.

Comment: Well, the thing is the first call to get_something() works as expected, but if I immediately call get_something() again, it fails. So there should be no query apart from these two calls.